# PHP Connection Error; Not allowed to connect to MySQL Server

Tags: php, html, sql, registration

I am trying to make a registration page where it adds the information to a SQL Table. Here is my PHP code to do this... Can anyone tell me what the error with this is?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("Correct Website is here","Correct Username","Correct Pass","Correct DB");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$DBsql = mysql_query("SELECT username, email from Profiles");
$sql = mysql_fetch_array($DBsql);

if(!($_POST['username'] == $sql['username']) && ($_POST['email'] == $sql['email'])) {
 if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2']){      
  $sql="INSERT INTO Profiles (firstName, lastName, username, email, password, region, group, verified)
  VALUES
  ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[username]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[region]','member','no')";
 }else{
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'window.alert("The passwords do not match.")'
   , '</script>';
 }
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'window.alert("That username or email is already in use.")'
   , '</script>';
}

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

It's giving these errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/1130): Host '31.170.161.96' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/a5349216/public_html/register.php on line 2

Failed to connect to MySQL: Host 'ip' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/username/public_html/register.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/username/public_html/register.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/username/public_html/register.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/username/public_html/register.php on line 27
```

Comment: please make sure, you are not posted actual DB hostname and username in your post. " 31.170.161.96 " and " a5349216 "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your mysql database is not on the same server(localhost) you need to give it access from a remote server for that mysql user/database for your server. See this article for some steps that might help you. It sounds like it might be remote.

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @lmcarreiro So I get a downvote for them changing their link? I answered the OPs question of telling him what the error meant. The link was a bonus. Anyway its fixed.

Comment: You told him what to do, not how... I just down voted it, so other answers that could help better took chance to appearing at the top instead of yours.

Comment: @lmcarreiro lol ok the site always give people an exact answer. sometimes it leads you to the answer. But he asked `what` the error was `Can anyone tell me what the error with this is` not how to fix it. :) Anyway, the new link should help

Answer (score 0):

Create new php file, just test with below syntax. let me know your error.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("Correct Website is here","Correct Username","Correct Pass","Correct DB");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/1130): Host 'ip' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/username/public_html/register.php on line 2

Failed to connect to MySQL: Host 'ip' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: reac this thread http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/allow-mysql-client-connection/

Comment: surly this is permission related prob. contact hosting provider