# I'm making a newsletter for a website and it does not connect to the server

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a newsletter for my promo website and it doesn't work for me, its a very simple form, just a register.php and connect.php to connect the database with the php. The code looks like this:

The connect.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "laidinis69";
$database = "promo";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
?>
```

The register.php

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$form_name = $_POST['name'];
$form_email = $_POST['email'];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE name="' .$form_name. '";';

if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        $query = 'INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES("'.$form_name.'","'.$form_email.'")';
        if(mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
            echo "registered";
        }
    } else {
        echo "already exists";
    }
}

header('Location: register.php');
?>
```

The form on my index.html file:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

When I press on Subscribe button, it redirects me to register.php and does not put in data in the database.

Comment: I believe you need `==` instead of `=` in the first `if-statement`.

Comment: Or do you really want to place `$result` inside an if-statement?

Comment: so there can be no $result in a if statement?

Comment: I don't think you can assign values in an if statement, just compare them with `==`.

Comment: Does the PHP error log indicate any warning/error?

Comment: it just redirects me to register.php file with the source code on the page

Comment: I'm not sure you need `header('Location: register.php');`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to try changing this line

```
if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) { ...
```

to this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email) VALUES ("'.$form_name.'","'.$form_email.'")';
```

and be sure to delete the extra `}` that goes with the `if-satement` you'll be deleting.

Comment: I get this error when i put my host in the $servername valuable.       Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/1130): Host '31.170.160.91' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/a1675995/public_html/connect.php on line 7

Comment: Try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386171/php-connection-error-not-allowed-to-connect-to-mysql-server) then.